# Override EditText selection functionality

Tags: android, pointers, text, android-edittext, selection

I am trying to create a new Text selection, copy and paste functionality that overrides that of android.
What I want to do is to change the pointer's image and style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four text selection styles defined (you can find these in your SDK's data folder):

- textSelectHandleLeft
- textSelectHandleRight
- textSelectHandle
- textSelectHandleWindowStyle

Which you can override with your own custom theme. Look for these in the resource XMLs for the SDK (/platforms/android-10/data/res/values) to see how they are built and how you can customize them.